# Adobe AEM/OSGI: How do I access an OSGI service from any class?

Tags: osgi, aem, sling

I have a service (located inside core/services) and service implementation (located core/services/impl).

I have an existing class (located inside core/impl/view/components) that extends com.adobe.cq.sightly.WCMUsePojo. Using getSlingScripterHelper, this class can acceess the service I mentioned above.

I'm trying to access the service without using WCMUsePojo. How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: I am curious, Why do you not want to extend wcmusepojo?

Answer (score 3):

You can get a service directly from service registry-

```
    final Bundle bundle = FrameworkUtil.getBundle(this.getClass());
    final BundleContext bundleContext = bundle.getBundleContext();
    ServiceReference<MyService> ref = bundleContext.getServiceReference(MyService.class)
    MyService myService = bundleContext.getService(ref);
    // use the service
    bundleContext.ungetService(ref);
```

Comment: Be aware that any approach of fetching a service from the registry is highly sensitive to timing issues. In OSGi a service can be published and unpublished at any time. So you can always have the issue that getServiceReference or getService return null. So you have to protect against null and also have to cope with the service not being there in the flow of your code. Generally it is safer to make your code a DS component and access the service through a reference.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@Reference` to call a service from any other class without using WCMUsePojo.

```
class MyClass
{
    @Reference
    private MyService myService;

    void myMethod()
    {
      myServie.callYourServiceMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: This only works if `MyClass` is a service/component itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the service from an HTL script backing bean you can use a Sling Model (instead of WcmUsePojo) and inject the reference to your service using the `@Inject` annotation.